# Sharepoint online - Hover over image to display information

Tags: sharepoint-online, mouseover

I got a Dev who reached out to the helpdesk about adding a feature to sharepoint that shows up when you hover the mouse over an image. In this example he wants to add, we hover over the picture of a staff member and it displays the name/title/ect.
I did some research and digging around in sharepoint and found options to modify code. I did look at some examples of what he wants to accomplish and checked the source, that's that point where I did not know what to do or look for... neither did the Dev.

Any help or a nudge to the right direction would be helpful! Thanks everyone